# Is the American government threatening Iran with war?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, iran, geopolitics, middle-east

[The Washington Institute for Near East Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Washington_Institute_for_Near_East_Policy) is an American think tank who is researching some programs all based on the middle east. This think tank has some former government officers including [R.James Woolsey Jr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._James_Woolsey_Jr.) **former CIA director** and [Condoleezza Rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condoleezza_Rice) who was secretary of state for [George W.Bush](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_W._Bush) who was offered "the Bin Ladin Determined To Strike in US" report, who was responsible for the Irak Weapons of mass destruction and authorisation of torture) and legendary [Henry Kissinger](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Kissinger) former Secretary of State

Years ago [Dr. Patrick Clawson](http://www.washingtoninstitute.org/experts/view/clawson-patrick) director of research said in a press conference:

> I frankly think crisis initiation is really tough, and it's hard for
>   me to see how the United States President can get us to war with
>   Iran...

[Video Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EB6qSX8rVeY)

Later he talks about many questionable American wars that could have started by false flag operations.

> ...we are in the game of using covert means against the Iranians...

This man also appears on the BBC and many other talk shows.

**Are there any other clear recent examples of USA agencies, or USA politicians threatening Iran with war?**

Comment: While I think very clearly that some American politicians are threatening war, war is after all foreign policy by other means and never off the table, I have no idea what you are trying to say in the first 4/5 of the "question' about false flag stuff.  It doesn't even seem to apply.

Comment: Comments deleted. If you would like to answer the question, please post a real answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer is "yes". Numerous arguments for it, one of the last - what Mike Pompeo claimed: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/global-opinions/wp/2018/05/21/mike-pompeo-gives-a-silly-speech-on-iran/?noredirect=on
This is, in fact, an ultimatum to a sovereign state.

But war? US army just cannot afford this. They have forces to bomb and invade weak, small countries like Iraq or Libya. But they doesn't have forces to attack a big country with modern air defence systems.

US can threat, or even do a single strike. But they definetly cannot invade and win, or force Iran to do something. They can start provocations to rise oil prices, to support US oil and gas companies - for now it is highly unprofitable companies.

Comment: A link is great, but the Pompeo claim would better be quoted in the body of the question. Also, one or two more examples of the *"numerous arguments"* would contribute better to this answer than the last two paragraphs : US capability of having a war is off-topic, the question is about threats.

Comment: Will search more for numerous. "offtop" - no-no. Question is "threatening with **war**". So talking about capabilities of what threat contains is not an offtop

Comment: Pompeo's quote "Do what we want, or else!" can be fairly construed as saying "Change or we're going to make you change", but saying that this is a threat of war is a huge logical leap. There are plenty of covert and other non-war ways of bending a country to one's will far short of war, a threat of war cannot be logically assumed here.

Comment: Don't think so. US have already tried nearly all non-war ways: initate protests about so-called 'freedom' and 'peace', tried to make an economic pressure (but EU in fact, blocked it). So, what's left? But US cannot afford this - it doesn't invade lands with meaningful defences, so this threats are just empty. And in such terms - yes, this is only words.

Comment: To quote the LA Times in 1990: "Already Iraq’s army is the fifth largest in the world, a million men and growing, larger in raw numbers than the U.S. Army and Marine Corps combined." The immediately preceding Iran-Iraq War was a tie. So it's pretty clear the US can and has invaded countries with Iran scale militaries.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that congressman and US president candidate [Ron Paul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Paul) suspected a contrived plan to attack Iran in 2007.

> I'm concerned however that a contrived "Gulf of Tonkin type incident"
>   may well occur...

[Video Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRB3UBz1KEQ)

On April 2018 National Security Advisor [John Bolton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_R._Bolton) said that the only solution is to change the regime itself and that would take place before 2019

[Video here](https://youtu.be/YG7DqFM6uxc?t=1m19s)